# Unable to use css property in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a text box in which value is 0 when page loads and I want if there is a 0 value in any numeric box, I want its background color to be changed on page load.

I want to do it using jquery only.

My code for this is not working, please find the demo link below and suggest on mistakes.

http://jsfiddle.net/ph43cuhj/1/

Below is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($("input:text").val()=='0')
        $(this).css('background-color','#c0c0c0');
});
```

Comment: You have to use a loop to select each input, because currently, $(this) is undefined...

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input:text").change(function () { //Bind change vent
        if ($(this).val() == '0') {
            $(this).css('background-color', '#c0c0c0');
        }else{
            $(this).css('background-color', '');
        }
    }).change(); //Trigger initally
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/cun2757n/)

Comment: why we have used .change() for this?

Comment: @Vaibhav, To trigger when page loads

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[type="text"]').each(function(){
    if( $(this).val() == '0' )
    { 
       $(this).css('background-color','#c0c0c0'); 
    }
  });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cLh48618/)

**EDIT :-**

OR Try This :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input:text').each(function(){
        if( $(this).val() == '0' )
        { 
           $(this).css('background-color','#c0c0c0'); 
        }
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sLcaz17n/)

Answer (score 0):

More compact:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type="text"][value="0"]').each(function () {
         $(this).css('background-color','#f00'); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i=0;i<$("body").find("input:text").length;i++)
 {
   var el=$("body").find("input:text").eq(i);
   if(el.val()==0){  el.css('background-color', '#c0c0c0');   }
   else  { el.css('background-color', '#000000');    }
}
```

try this code in document ready function